# OpenSSL SSL_get_verify_result returns error 18 for google.com

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing my own C/C++ library to handle TLS streams. And I'm stuck on OpenSSL refusing to verify google.com's cert. This seems to only happen to google.com. `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443` can correctly verify google.com's certificate

```
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = *.google.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
```

But my code

```cpp
...
SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx);
...
// create socket
SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, nullptr);
// handshake, etc...
...
SSL_get_verify_result(ssl); // always return X509_V_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

Why the command successfully validates the certificate but my code can't?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your truststore does not contain an exact match for the google certificate but will not take the additional steps that your browser typically does verify the signature associated with the certificate. A great resource for the openssl basics: https://opensource.com/article/19/6/cryptography-basics-openssl-part-1

Additionally, your specific verify result can be found here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/verify.html

X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT - what you've received is a self signed certificate.

Hope that helps!